# Missing /dev/shm

Tags: google-chrome

when I tried opening google-chrome in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I received the following error:

```
[1976:2032:299999600:ERROR:shared_memory_posix.cc(171)] Creating shared memory in        /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.0ApmLo failed: No such file or directory
   [1976:2032:299999742:ERROR:shared_memory_posix.cc(174)] Unable to access(W_OK|X_OK) /dev/shm: No such file or directory
   [1976:2032:299999773:FATAL:shared_memory_posix.cc(176)] This is frequently caused by       incorrect permissions on /dev/shm.  Try 'sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm' to fix.
```

However, when I tried

> sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm

, I discovered that /dev/shm did not in fact exist. I don't know what happened, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Since 11.10 Ubuntu migrated to /run/shm instead /dev/shm, see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/TechnicalOverview/Beta2#Upgrades).
To solve the problem, you can do a softlink like this:

```
sudo ln -s /run/shm /dev/shm
```